# Why does TCP sends more than 1 ack per packet?

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpdump

My source sends packets of 4794 bytes (at least according to the capturing it looks like 1 packet each), however, the destination machine sends **2 acks** for **every** packet sent from source.
I've tried changing the read stack size of the destination machine (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem`) to higher value than 4906 (which is the default minimum) but I didn't see any change.
Both systems running linux (centos).
I use `tcpdump` and 'wireshark' to analyze the captures.

Here is a screenshot of wireshark :

[image]

The src is 172.16.33.237, dst is 172.16.34.111.
Notice each 4794 packet gets 2 acks.
The 194 bytes packets are application response of the destination (and I believe not relevant for this discussion)

Comment: include pictures  from wireshark.   You can cross off parts of the picture you want to be hidden

Comment: i'm no expert but maybe(I don't know but maybe), it'd be more clear if you showed e.g. the SYN, the SYN ACK, the FIN, e.t.c.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of NIC's use [Large Segment Offload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_segment_offload) where the NIC driver is responsible for chopping up the TCP data into smaller packets for transmission, rather than the system CPU. tcpdump/Wireshark capture traffic before it has been chopped by the NIC which is why you can can sometimes see packets larger than the MTU of the interface in the capture.

Assuming a standard MTU of 1500 Bytes is being used, that would require 4 packets to be sent. TCP [Delayed Acknowledgement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment) is another performance feature which will typically result in an ACK being sent for every second packet.

Comment: Hi, Notice I see 2 acks per packet and not 1 ack for 2 packets, I've also tried setting the mtu in both systems to 9000 and it didn't change this

Comment: What is the MTU being used by your two devices?

Comment: I started with 1500 and raised it to 9000, in both cases I get 2 acks per packet

Comment: Ok, lets stick with the standard MTU of 1500. With an MTU of 1500, it's impossible for a single packet to be 4794 Bytes. This therefore indicates that you are seeing the effects of Large Segment offload in Wireshark where the data hasn't yet been split up. A single "packet" of 4794 Bytes would require 4 actual packets to be send. Delayed ACK would send an ACK packet for every second packet. Therefore you will see *two* acks for your *one* "packet" when viewed in Wireshark.

Comment: You should also see that the two ACKs acknowledge different chunks of data.

Comment: That makes sense, but what about when MTU is 9000 ?

Comment: @SagiLow MTU is not supported by most networks, and may not be supported by your routers and/or switches.  You need to ensure the whole network path supports large packet sizes.  Normally this is only done for limited subsets of a LAN, usually for data backbones.

Comment: I've used the method described here : https://www.mylesgray.com/hardware/test-jumbo-frames-working/ to ensure the MTU setting indeed takes affect .

Comment: If your source is sending TCP packets, are you also adjusting the MSS?

Comment: Never heard of it, Ill try setting it now. Thanks

Comment: Why would you be changing MTU settings if you haven't even heard of MSS? Please research technologies yourself before asking why they don't do what you think they should.

Comment: Hi MarkoPolo, I did a research and looked, however, I didn't encounter MSS  before, this is why I asked my question, this is the idea of this website, to get missing information, sometimes it's widely known and sometimes it's not.  thank you for your assistance anyway,

Comment: I guess I (mistakenly) assumed that somebody comfortable with using Jumbo Frames and modifying TCP receive windows would have at least heard of Maximum Segment Size. Apologies if I misread the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Read the full article [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/).

You can tune TCP Buffer size. First please type the following commands to check the configured values:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mem
```

Find the maximum amount for receive socket memory:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default

$ cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max
```

For the send socket memory:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default

$ cat /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max
```

And maximum amount for memory buffers:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/core/optmem_max
```

Tune Values (wmem and rmem):

You have to set maximum send wmem and receive rmem buffer size to 12 MB on all protocols. Please follow the commands:

```
# echo 'net.core.wmem_max=12582912' >> /etc/sysctl.conf

# echo 'net.core.rmem_max=12582912' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Set minimum, initial and maximum size(specify in bytes):

```
# echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_rmem= 10240 87380 12582912' >> /etc/sysctl.conf

# echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_wmem= 10240 87380 12582912' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Enlarge the transfer window:

```
# echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Enable timestamps as defined in RFC1323:

```
# echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Enable acknowledgements:

```
# echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

If connection metrics for the root cache is set while closing the connection, then:

```
# echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Set maximum number of packets for the Input side:

```
# echo 'net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 5000' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Please reload the changes:

```
# sysctl -p
```

View the changes:

```
# tcpdump -ni eth0
```

Comment: Whilst useful information, I'm not sure how this answers the original question.

Answer (score 0):

MarkoPolo is correct. But he didn't mention that if you use a network tap you will capture the actual packets as they are sent over the network and it would make more sense. What you're are seeing is 3 packets combined into one. The receiving TCP is utilizing delayed ACK and acknowledging every one or two packets.

The 194 byte application response is relevant because of the stop and wait behavior of the sending device. This pattern is what triggered your question. If this were simply a unidirectional bulk transfer with no server response a very different pattern would develop.

Also, setting your MTU to 9000 on a network with a default route, bad. This will lead to problems and accomplish nothing